# I want to use double metaphone algorithm in stored procedure does oracle have any inbuilt function for this?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, metaphone

i want to use double metaphone algorithm in oracle database.Does oracle have inbuilt function for this.

Comment: A very quick internet search for "oracle plsql double metaphone" turns up this https://github.com/AliArdaOrhan/Double_Metaphone github project...

Comment: [Oracle EDQ product](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/data-quality/edqhelp/Content/processor_library/transformation/metaphone.htm) has a Double Metaphone implementation but that is external to the database. There is no Metaphone built-in PL/SQL library, although the web hosts various implementations in PL/SQL. If you're on 11gR2 you should really consider using [Oracle Text Name Search](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/search.htm#CCAPP9534).

Answer (score 0):

No.  But you can find the PL/SQL source code for double metaphone on the net and implement it.